# Route all network traffic through Pi for logging

Tags: ethernet, internet, dns

I am using eero for my wireless mesh and main router.

Setup is Cable Modem --> Eero --> Wifi / ethernet switch

I am getting some spam / security notices from spectrum (only real option here) and want to try and correlate.

Eero has no logging.

Can I route all traffic through a pi using eero? I don't think so I think I might have messed up getting the eero.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I route all traffic through a pi using eero?

If you can plug it in via ethernet, maybe.  That alone probably will not work, because only traffic for the Pi will be routed that way.  However, if you disable wifi from the eero and make the Pi the wifi router, then yes.  This will be a significant performance drop for the network, but if it still all at least works, then you should be able to do an audit.

The other option is to use the Pi as a wifi sniffer.  For that to be effective, you probably have to ensure that it is the first node to connect to the wifi, and that it stays connected ("probably" because this depends on what form of security the wlan uses; if you read around about wifi sniffing you will likely encounter a reference to this issue).  Note that the eero likely can detect the presence of the sniffer and may cut it off. Sniffing will be less effective in the sense that there is no guarantee you are really getting all the traffic, but it will not hamper the network performance.

Answer (score 0):

There are some small 5 ports managed switches that has the feature `port mirroring`. And with `port mirroring` you can mirror the traffic either on the Cable Modem or Eero ethernet port. And then you mirror that traffic to a port where the Raspberry Pi is connected.

This devices is called "Wired TAP", "LAN TAP" or "Network TAP" and there is a lot of HowTos is you search for the above device names together with Raspberry Pi.